# Sending and Receiving MMS

Tags: android

Can anyone suggest me some good link for sending and receiving mms in android as well as it includes the source code

Thanks in advance
Seshagopal

Comment: This question is not very good. It could easily be improved by showing the terms you typed into [a](http://duckduckgo.com) [search](http://google.com) [engine](http://bing.com), along with the results that you found that were unhelpful. Most people here are answering questions on their own time, and showing your effort shows respect to those people.

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21748209/receive-mms-messages-in-android-kitkat

Answer (score 0):

Here you have all the information with an example project to send and receive mms: http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android

Good luck!

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452808/sending-and-receiving-mms-in-android